# iPhone 4 without a SIM card

Tags: iphone

I just recently purchased an iPhone 4 on Amazon that doesn't have a SIM card. I was planning to use it as an iPod, because my parents wouldn't and couldn't buy me a phone with a plan. So I was just wondering if I could activate it on the spot when I get it in the mail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but the CDMA (Verizon and Sprint) iPhone 4 does not have a SIM card slot, and thus doesn't require one to activate the iPhone on a carrier.

Comment: Which might be about 1% of the world's phones - the rest need a SIM to activate.